# Multiple transformations in GStreamer videoflip

Tags: gstreamer

Is there a way to apply multiple transformations to a GStreamer video stream using `videoflip` without needing two distinct pipeline elements?

In other words, I'm currently doing something like:

```
videotestsrc
! videoflip method=clockwise
! videoflip method=horizontal-flip
! fakesink
```

What I'm asking is if it's possible to combine the two (or more) `videoflip` elements into something like:

```
! videoflip method=clockwise,horizontal-flip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in GStreamer (unless the element is specially design to support it)

In this **specific** use case, you can use `videoflip method=upper-left-diagonal` to replace clockwise and horizontal flip
(or use `videoflip method=6` for short)

In general, setting 2 value for a property is not possible.
In your case, GStreamer will understand that you want to set a value "clockwise,horizontal-flip" to property "method", which is obviously wrong.